# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Menu' in 'D:\

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I tried to download

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --force
```

after

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
npm install @material-ui/core
```

and that all not works
I got only errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LRez.png)

My code of the Appbar is simple from ui materials

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';

export default function Appbar() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

and main "App.js" file

```
import './App.css';
import Appbar from './components/Appbar' 


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Appbar/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error of the compilation is

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles' in 'D:\oop\studentsystem\studentfrontend\src\components'
WARNING in [eslint] 
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Menu' in 'D:\oop\studentsystem\studentfrontend\src\components'
ERROR in ./src/components/Appbar.js 11:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Menu' in 'D:\oop\studentsystem\studentfrontend\src\components'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I dont know how to solve that problem, because i have just today started to learn React js and frontend generally.
Sorry for my stupidity, help please me,  if you can.:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to install the right packages:

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

@mui and @material-ui are 2 different things

[Here is the Guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/)